# insert only filled rows from table to json array by check each row if it is not empty insert data in array otherwise skip that row

Tags: html, jquery, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

In my scenario i have a table which inputs data from user and save the table rows first in json array then pass this array to MVC controller using ajax.
[image]

The data in table (eg name eid student id )are fill from server side from controller using jquery then user have to provide marks against each student.then the table data along with marks pass from view to controller using ajax.

Scenario for Problem:
if user fill some rows not all ones then only filled rows data should be inserted in json array.How can I achieve this using Jquery . first check if the row is filled then add that row data in array

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClarderSousSecteurID", "---  Tous  ---")
<input id="date" value='@DateTime.Now.ToString(" dd/mm/yyyy")' />
<input id="date" type="hidden" value='@ViewBag.P_No' />

<table id="tableId" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Student_id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Did he perform well</th>
            <th>According to Criteria</th>
            <th>To the point</th>
            <th>EID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="savebtn" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" style="display:none;" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var date;
    var val;
    $("#ClarderSousSecteurID").change(function () {
        val = $("#ClarderSousSecteurID").val();
        $("#tableId > tbody").empty();
        date = $("#date").val();
        $("#savebtn").show();
        alert("selected=" + val + date)

        var data = JSON.stringify({

            'val': val
        });




        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/judge_dashboard/Getstudents",
            data: data,

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var tr;
                //Append each row to html table
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].stud_id + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].stud_name + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td><input id='one'></td>");
                    tr.append("<td><input id='two'></td>");
                    tr.append("<td><input id='three'></td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].E_id + "</td>");

                    $('table').append(tr);
                }
                alert(r + "=== record(s) inserted." + data);
            }
        });


    });

    $("body").on("click", "#savebtn", function () {
        var marks = new Array();
        $("#tableId TBODY TR").each(function () {

            {
                alert("filled row")
                var row = $(this);
                var details = {};
                details.DATE = date;
                details.One_marks = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                details.Two_marks = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
                details.Three_marks = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
                details.Eid = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
                details.Contest_id = val;
                marks.push(details);
            }

        });

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.\

        var data = JSON.stringify({
            'judges': marks,
            'val': val
        });
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Contest_judge/InsertJudge",
            data: data,

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {


                alert(r + "=== record(s) inserted." + data);
            }
        });
    });








</script>
```

Note: order of data in Json Array should be following
Date,one(or One_marks),two(or Two_marks),three(or Three_marks),Eid

because I have to insert the whole row as a object in database from controller so the order of column elements for each row  in json array matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample, I wasn't sure if you were labeling your inputs, so this example has no-name inputs, but inherits their context from the header row.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#savebtn", function() {
  var marks = new Array();
  $("#tableId tbody tr").each(function() {
    let mark = {
      Eid: $(this).find('td').eq(5).text(),
      DATE: 'date',
      Contest_id: 'val'
    }
    let empty = true;
    $(this).find('td').each(function(i, o) {
      if ($(o).find('input').length > 0 && $(o).find('input').eq(0).val().trim() !== '') {
        mark[$("#tableId thead th").eq(i).text()] = $(o).find('input').eq(0).val();
        empty = false;
      }

    })
    if (!empty) marks.push(mark);

  });

  //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.\

  var data = JSON.stringify({
    'judges': marks,
    'val': 'val'
  });

  console.log(data)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student_id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Did he perform well</th>
      <th>According to Criteria</th>
      <th>To the point</th>
      <th>EID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>223</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>323</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td>333</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id='savebtn'>save</button>
```